# How to apply alignment to colored text in c++ output

Tags: c++, colors, alignment

I am trying to align my output with setw and left in c++ as follows:

```
string s[] = {"S1", "S2", "S10", "S4", "S5", "S11", "S3", "S7"};
for (int i=4; i<=11; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<8; j++) {
          if (j%2==0) {
              cout << setw(8) << left << s[i-4];
          } else {
              cout << setw(8) << left << "* ";
          }
      }
      cout << endl;
  }
```

This code works pretty good. But if I add the color to the text by something like below, it messes up the alignment.

```
  string s[] = {"\033[1;31mS1\033[0m", "\033[1;31mS2\033[0m", "\033[1;31mS10\033[0m", "\033[1;31mS4\033[0m", "\033[1;31mS5\033[0m", "\033[1;31mS11\033[0m", "\033[1;31mS3\033[0m", "\033[1;31mS7\033[0m"};
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this code so to have both color and alignment work at the same time? Thanks

Comment: You will have to write a bunch of code that understands escape sequences, and formats the colored text taking into consideration that escape sequences take up no real estate. The C++ library has absolutely no knowledge of escape sequences. For all it knows, `std::cout` goes to some file. You will have to do all this work by yourself.

Comment: Do the color codes have to be part of the original strings, or is it fine to add them later when writing to a stream?

Comment: What @cigien proposes sounds good. Stream the escape sequences before `setw` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have strings that you both, want to format, as well as add color codes, then you can do this easily by streaming the color code sequences *before* you stream the formatted text. This way, the color codes and the alignment won't interfere with each other:

```
std::cout << "\033[1;31m" << std::setw(8) << std::left  << s[i-4] << "\033[0m";
```

If however, the color codes are part of the strings, then you will have to put in some work to separate the strings from the color codes. Be careful though, since not all color codes have the same number of characters.